# Algorithm to find newest of n values

Tags: c, algorithm

I am working on a problem where three memory pages are available and data is supposed to be written in one of the pages.

To keep history the data is first written to 1st page, and when that is full the next page shall be used. Finally, the last page is also full so we have to erase the data in the first page and use the first page. And so on...

How can I know which of the pages is the 'oldest'? How do I determine which to erase?

I think that a counter is needed, and this counter increments every time a new page is used. The counter values is read in the beginning to find which page is the newest and then the next page is the oldest (since circular approach). However, eventually the counter will overflow, the counter restarts and it will not be possible to be sure which value is the highest (since the new value is 0).

Example:

- 0 0 0 (from beginning)
- 1 0 0 (page0 was used)
- 1 2 0 (page1 was used)
- 1 2 3 (page2 was used)
- 4 2 3 (page0 was used)
- 4 5 3 (page1 was used)
- ...
- 255 0 254 (I dont know... )

Is the problem clear? Otherwise I can try to re-explain.

Comment: Why not simply update the value with the old value+1 modulo 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a technique used in **EEPROM wear leveling**. The concept is that since EEPROM usually has a limited life of write/erase cycles, we balance out the wear in the memory so that effectively the life increases. Since the data in EEPROM stays in the controller even on power off, we may have to store log values of some variables periodically on the EEPROM for further use.

One simple approach that you can follow is that as suggested in the comments you can update the counter by keep calculating (counter modulo 3).

Other (more general) approach is to have three registers for the counter. Whenever you have to write to a page, first scan these three registers and check the combinations where `(C[i] != C[i-1] + 1)`

```
0 0 0 
1 0 0  // 1 to 0
1 2 0  // 2 to 0
1 2 3  // 3 to 1
4 2 3  // 4 to 2 
...
255 0 254  // 0 to 254.
```

This link has more information about this subject: [Is there a general algorithm for microcontroller EEPROM wear leveling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667491/is-there-a-general-algorithm-for-microcontroller-eeprom-wear-leveling)

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. I am trying out this algorithm and my test stopped at this:

255 0 1   (0 != 255 + 1) => TRUE. But the '1' shall be used. 

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @user3201357 I don't think you can ever have 255, 0, 1. It should be 255, 0, 254. You can probably make the type of your counter variable as 8-bit (like char). This way it should automatically rollover to 0 if you add 1 to 255. Otherwise you always have the modulo operator.

Comment: I was wrong. I had forgot to (unsigned char)-type cast. Sorry about my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of using a circular buffer is a good one. All you need in addition to that are to indices, one to point at the oldest page and one to point at the newest. You need to update those indices whenever you add or replace a page.

The reason you need to is that in beginning -- until the buffer is full -- only one of them will be advancing while the other will remain stationary.

Answer (score 0):

I do this kind of cycles like this:

```
// init
int page0=adress of page0; // oldest data
int page1=adress of page1; // old data
int page2=adress of page2; // actual data (page for write)

// after page 2 is full
int tmp;
tmp=page0;
page0=page1;
page1=page2;
page2=tmp;
```

- this way you allways know which page is which
- page 0 allways the oldest data
- page 1 allways the old data
- page 2 allways actual data
- it is easily extendable to any number of pages
- instead of adress you can store the page number ... use what is more suitable for your task